# Mule ESB Batch exceptions not registered

Tags: database, mule, connection-pooling

We have a *Mule ESB Batch* application that reads many records from a *CSV* and tries to write them to a *DB*. We need the batch to stop on the first exception (`max failed records = 0`). There is a batch step with the database record insert.

We modified the db connection on purpose to make it fail.

We've noticed that although the *DB* processor raises an exception, the batch step seems to don't care and keeps receiving new records to process.

The *DB* connection uses *c3p0 pooling* (it is included by design in *Mule 3.5.2*). It seems as if the acquire attemps from *c3p0* are still running (`30 by default`) and until they finish, the step is not "declared" as failed.

**How can we fix this?** (the `acquireRetryAttemps` property is not exposed to be changed).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> We've noticed that although the DB processor raises an exception, the
>   batch step seems to don't care and keeps receiving new records to
>   process.

You can catch this exception and raise more strong one which will actually break your batch.

Also, based on provided explanation you do work with exception handling since you see DB exception. So, maybe, your exception handling is not good. It's hard to say without code. Can you provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?